# Alpha numeric sorting in Crystal Report

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

I'm trying to sort a string field in crystal report that contains numbers and letters

I have:

```
21B
1
10
11B
33A
11
200
120C
11A
50
120A
1B
```

and I like to sort it like this: first numeric then letters

```
1
1B
10
11
11A
11B
21B
33A
50
120A
120C
200
```

I've tried

```
if length({Table.field}) = 1 then
"0" + {Table.field})
else if NumericText(right({Table.field}, 1) 
then {Table.field}
else "0" + {Table.field}
```

but it doesn't give me the result I'm looking for

Answer (score 2):

try like below

Create a formula `@Sort` and write below formula

```
val({Table.field})
```

Place the formula in section where you placed fields and supress it. Now sort the records with respect to the created formula.

Comment: It looks like this only works for numbers but doesn't take the letters in account

Comment: As I told you don't display this on your report.... display original filed and supress this but sort according to this field

Comment: This worked for me. I have warehouse aisles that start with numbers then with letters. To sort correctly the single and double digit aisles, sorting by Val worked perfectly. This is the answer!